# Default tag on Stackdriver logs

Tags: logging, stackdriver, google-cloud-logging

how would be possible to send log to Stackdriver and decide which fields to show on the main line as in the [embedded image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5Sih.png) with Browser version, http method, response status code, etc. ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We just launched a new feature to allow you to dynamically choose which fields are displayed:
https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/release-notes#april_10_2018

Answer (score 0):

Control over which fields show up in the un-expanded "summary" line of the logs viewer UI is [now available](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/release-notes#may_8_2018).

See https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/overview#custom-fields